# Class "super" variable

Tags: python, class, variables

There is a class as following:

```
class N: 
    def __init__(self, node_id): 
        self.id = node_id      # id (as an integer for example) 
        self.super = 0 
        self.color = 0
```

It is about creating a node. As you can see, there is an attribute, super. I want to call the color of the supernode.

I tried to implement:

```
node.color = node.super.color
```

but, it was wrong implementation. Do you have any idea how to get the information of other node?

Comment: `self.super` is set to `0`, so it's an integer, and integers don't have colors (at least for the non-synesthetic among us).  I seem to be missing something...

Comment: @SvenMarnach is quite right. Also, rather than saying "it was wrong implementation," you should paste the actual error message.

Comment: What super node are you even referring to? Is class N supposed to be able to store a reference to another node instance in its self.super attribute?

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly pass the parent node -or at least its color, to the class init function 
- there is no way a simplist node class can "guess" how it is connected with other node objects.

One way to go is:

```
class N(object):
    def __init__(self, node_id, parent_node):
         self.id = node_ide
         self.parent = parent_node
         self.color = 0
   # and you canget parentnode color with self.node.color
```

Comment: This looks right to me. It has that missing piece from my question about whether the OP wanted to store a reference to another node instance

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Also a typo on node_ide... and don't call him Shirley